# How to use @RequestBody to receive a data object which contains foreign keys?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to use RequestBody to receive a database object posted from frontend and convert it to a Java Object. And this database object contains the foreign keys.

Course Table structure:

```
create table course
(
id bigint auto_increment
    primary key,
code varchar(255) null,
name varchar(255) null,
department_id int null
)
engine=MyISAM;

create index FK8m89mn0y32bm9vko2bcfkag53
    on course (department_id);
```

[Course Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EpUi.png)

`department_id` is the FK reference department table.

And here is my Course Entity:

```
package com.elfstack.aims.api.entity;
import lombok.Data;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Data
@Entity
public class Course {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String code;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private Department department;
}
```

[Course Entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqpDf.png)

When I want to create a new Course record, I send a JSON Object from frontend:

```
{"code":"123","name":"123","department_id":123}
```

And I use this method to handle this request:

```
@PostMapping("/courses")
public JSON createCourse(@RequestBody Course course) {...}
```

Of course, I can't get `department_id` in this way, but I also think it's not a good idea to send entier `Department` object from frontend when I want to create a new course record, so what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There could be 2 approaches to achieve your desire.

1. A recommended approach is to create a DTO object which mapped with your JSON structure and convert it to your entity object in Controller.

```
@Data
public class CourseDto {
  private String code;
  private String name;
  private String departmentId;
}

@PostMapping("/courses")
public JSON createCourse(@RequestBody CourseDto courseDto) {
  final Course course = covertToEntity(courseDto)
  ...
}
```

2. Keep your current implementation but change the structure of your JSON string to something like

```
{  "code":"123",
   "name":"123",
   "department": {
      "id": 123
   }
}
```

Note: Only the department id is required. Hibernate can reference your object correctly, but it depends on how you want to set the cascade rule as well.